# Penetration testing with WMAP, only for my domain, not the others with the same IP?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, security, dns, nmap

My domain got massively hacked, so I'm doing some penetration testing with it using WMAP and NMAP etc.

However, I believe it's on shared hosting, so running tests on 182.34.xx.xxx (the IP address for my site, will also impact ALL sites sharing that IP address.

WMAP and NMAP seem to require an IP address and do not deal with hostnames 'mysite.com'.

I have discovered that 182.34.xx.xxx/~username leads to my site though.

I just want to make sure I am running tests on my OWN site, and none of the others.

I'm using Ubuntu, nmap, wmap and syn.

Comment: Nmap will accept a hostname, no problem. But make sure you get permission from your hosting provider for your test, or they may suspend your account.

Comment: I don’t know about WMAP, but I’m pretty sure NMAP doesn’t do tests that are relevant to a web site or server.  I believe NMAP primarily tests (attacks) the whole host, so there’s no way you can use it without impacting “ALL sites sharing that IP address.”

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a local lighttpd or Apache proxy that redirects to the appropriate directory on your host, and then point WMAP/NMAP to `localhost`. You may wish to verify that other sites are totally inaccessible through the proxy before running the tests, though.

Here's an example for lighttpd:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
      "^(.*)" => "/~username$1"
)
proxy.server = (
  "" => (
    (
      "host" => "182.34.xx.xxx",
      "port" => 80
    )
  )
)
```